# I have a large set of data, i want to realize the following action but takes too much time. How can I optimize it?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, bigdata

I am working on a set of data which i need to clean a bit before, around `400.000` lines,

Two actions to make :
- Resale Invoice Month are strings `M201705`, i want to make a column named 
 `Year` with only the year in that case `2017`

- Some commercial products which are string also, end up with `TR`, i want to delete the `TR` from these products. for example `M23065TR` i want to change all the products in that case in `M23065`, but in the column there are also products names which are already good `M340767` for example
  There is my code just under, it needs more than `2h` to run, would you have a solution to simplify it so it takes less time. 
  Thank you very much

```py
for i in range(Ndata.shape[0]):
    Ndata.loc[i,'Year']=Ndata.loc[i,'Resale Invoice Month'][1:5]
    if (Ndata['Commercial Product Code'][i][-2:]=='TR')==True:
        Ndata.loc[i,'Commercial Product Code']=Ndata.loc[i,'Commercial Product Code'][:-2]
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `pandas`, always try to vectorize, not using loop.

You can do something like:

```
# for Year
NData['Year'] = Ndata['Resale Invoice Month'].str[1:5]

# remove trailing TR, only row have it
idx = Ndata['Commercial Product Code'].str[-2:]=='TR'
Ndata.loc[idx, 'Commercial Product Code'] = Ndata[idx].str[:-2]
```

Comment: May be: `Ndata['Commercial Product Code'] = Ndata['Commercial Product Code'].str.replace('TR','')`

Comment: Hi @hunzter, thanks for your answer. It doesn't seem to work. I have an error telling : ...

Comment: hi @Rickou95 there is an syntax error, I have fixed that. Must be `Ndata['Commercial Product Code'].str`, not `Ndata.str['Commercial Product Code']`